# mkdir() permission denied - PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, macos, macos-sierra

I am trying to make an XML doc based on a HTML form input. However, once the php is executed, I get a page that says: 
[image]

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$customer = $dom->createElement("customer");
$dom->appendChild($customer);

$dir = 'XMLfiles';
if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
 $oldmask = umask(0);  // helpful when used in linux server  
 mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cust = $dom->createElement("customer");
$customer->appendChild($cust);
$name = $dom->createElement("fname",$fname);
$cust->appendChild($name);
$emailxml = $dom->createElement("Email", $email);
$cust->appendChild($emailxml);
$contactxml = $dom->createElement("Contact", $contact);
$cust->appendChild($contactxml);
$passxml = $dom->createElement("Password", $password);
$cust->appendChild($passxml);
//$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save($dir."/customer.xml");

?>
```

Point me in the right direction and I will learn it.

Thanks everyone!

PS: I am trying this on a mac (if that makes any difference in giving permissions and stuff). I am new to programming, so please ignore anything that's irrelevant or advise me.

Comment: Can you remove the final `?>` from your PHP script and see what happens? or what does it look like when you view the document source?

Comment: @Scuzzy: Just did. Still the same as in the first image ( a blank xml ) :(.

Comment: Can you use `echo $dom->saveXML();` instead of `$dom->save("customer.xml");`, this will echo it inline instead of writing it disk. `$dom->saveXML();` on it's own need echo or further processing.

Comment: @Scuzzy, I thought that saveXML is for inline processing and I needed to save the XML as a file so I used save(). But yeah, I did as suggested and still the same result. Nothing being displayed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error sorry, maybe reivew the `name="submit"` submit element of your form?

Comment: @Scuzzy, hey, I just edited the post and added the HTML form as well. I am not able to understand the error. Would the HTML code help in any way?

Comment: Maybe, I do see you reference `fname/lname` but it's `firstname/lastname` in the form. also you have `name=password` twice

Comment: @Scuzzy, that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out. Even though I changed them, I am not able to solve the error.  When you tried, did you get the XML output?

Comment: I did when I used `echo $dom->saveXML();` Check the PHP log or turn on verbose error reporting maybe

Comment: @Scuzzy, I did not use echo before $dom->saveXML() :P. Thanks heaps! But I also wanted to save it as a file. If I use save(customer.xml), where does the file get saved? How do I access the xml file on my drive?

Comment: It saves to the directory relative to the current script execution, at which point your `header('Content-type: text/xml');` is useless if you're not echoing the XML content.

Comment: @Scuzzy. I added the save(customer.xml) line and removed the header() and isset(post(submit)) and I got this error: Warning: DOMDocument::save(customer.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Assignment2/savecust.php on line 31. (on the line where save(customer.xml) is written. How do I add permissions?

Comment: Not sure on that one sorry, it can be system dependant (looks like mac osx which I know nothing about)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a post on apple support that explained adding permissions. I just did this :View Info -> file sharing and permissions -> changed everything to read/write.

I will close the question now.